# Android:- change the text on buttons sequentially using animation

Tags: android, animation, button, text

I have a sequence of buttons in android and I need to change the text of those buttons sequentially (slowly one by one) How can I achieve this? I cant apply any animation here?

Comment: You can use handler for that....

Answer (score 0):

Its really hard to tell exactly 
what you want to do here but one option could be to use a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) You could repeat changing the text of the buttons at whatever intervals you want. You could use a `for loop` to iterate over the buttons

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
```

// your buttons something like this

```
int[] ButtonArray = {R.id.button1,R.id.button2.....};
String[] stringArray = {"Hi","Hello","oi"....};

 // get all the button
 private Button[] myButtons=new Button[buttonArray.length];

 for(int i = 0; i < buttonArray.length ; i++){
      myButtons[i] = (Button) findViewById(mAlphabetsId[i]); 

 }
```

//Handler to do repetitive task

.................
Start The repetitive task

```
counterValue = 0;
Size =buttonArray.length; //Number of buttons
 myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable, speed);
```

.............................

```
   private Runnable mMyRunnable = new Runnable()
{

    public void run()
    { 
        if(counterValue<Size){  
           myButtons[counterValue].setText(stringArray[CounterValue]);    
          myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable, 1000);  //Call again with 1 sec delay
         counterValue++;
        }else{
             myHandler.removeCallbacks(mMyRunnable);
             counterValue=0;    
        }

    }
};
```

This code may contain errors since I did it in a hurry.  Try it first.

Let me know if you get stuck.